# How to manually config nevim lsp and linter to make it smarter?

Tags: neovim, vim-plugin, linter

I'm switching from vscode to neovim (currently using lunarvim). One problem bothered me most is that if my included file don't use relative path, but handle these dependencies in Makefile instead, then the lsp failed to navigate, and make linter report mistakes because some definitions and declarations are in other files and can't be located.

[image]

I face the same situation in vscode too, but by writting [c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) file, the intellisense will work normally.

If there is any way to write down some hints for neovim lsp? Or maybe if there is some plugin that can auto detect the Makefile or CMakeList file and solve the problem?

Comment: If using clangd as LSP, it will detect `compile_commands.json`, which could be generated by cmake under project root dir.

Comment: @halfelf Thanks for your  hint, I use `bear` to generate `compile_commands.json` and it works fine for me.